# Column not copying over through conditional in R

Tags: r

I am trying to read in a table in R then check if the category column of the table matches a certain value, if it does copy the value of a different column over. Thus creating an array of values who's category tag matches with the conditional

```
B <- read.table("tableFile2.data", sep=";", header=TRUE, row.names=2)
B$new <- ifelse(B$category == "mammal", B$animal, NA)
B$new
```

With the file

```
wasted space
more waste
animal;RowName;category
dog;a;mammal
spider;b;insect
monkey;c;mammal
sardine;d;fish
Jeromy;J;angry
```

However when I execute this and print B$new
I get the values

```
1 NA 2 NA
```

So the program clearly works for the condition but the correct value is not being copied over

Comment: What does data.frame B look like?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the first query (if the file actually looks like the one that you have described in the question) should be:

```
B <- read.table("tableFile2.data", sep=";", header=TRUE, skip=2)
```

For accomplishing the above mentioned task, you can run this query:

```
B$new <- ifelse(B$category == "mammal", as.character(B$animal), NA)
```

The reason behind the output that you mentioned is the fact that in this data frame B, the column 'animal' is taken as a FACTOR and not character.

The numbers that you are getting in your output are similar to one obtained if you cast B$animal as 'integer'.